# Reordering the position of usercontrols on a ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am working on a page that has user controls that are arranged in a particular layout. I am modifying that page to support reordering the position based on user's preferences. So, essentially, on load, I have information on where I need to position the different user controls.

I can think of 2 approaches:

- Do the reordering on the client side. This is not ideal for the user
  as they see the reordering happening.
- Do the reordering on the server side. This requires me to do a lot of
  rewrite to dynamically load the user controls based on preferences.

Are there any other ways of accomplishing what I am trying to do?

Comment: What is the datasource of these controls? I'd imagine if it inherits from IEnumerable (Entity Framework, Linq -to SQL, even plain old List<>) you could simply change the OrderBy and re-bind your datasource, assuming your layout is done in a Repeater or other similar control.

Comment: They are user controls (ascx).

Comment: Since the Page.Controls or WhateverContainerObject.Controls object is IEnumerable, can we orderby there? something like

    Page.Controls.Cast<Control>().ToList();

Then clear existing controls and use the above statement to do OrderBy or something like that.

Comment: Thats an interesting idea. I need to place the user controls in 3 different columns based on order. What method in the page life cycle should I be overriding?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. If it was just Page Controls and no postback it would probably work in Init... depends on whether your usercontrols need viewstate, session, etc. You won't have access to that stuff in PreInit, but I'm always a fan of earlier-the-better. I think the order of control draw ends up being determined in PreRender or Render so I'd try before that. I think it's kind of experimental at this point :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easier way; rendering is controlled by the parent container rendering them.  It is possible to create a container, and have full control over the ordering of the rendering of its children (by overriding the RenderChildren method).  It's not the easiest option, but it can work.  The steps are:

- Create a class that inherits from ContainerControl
- Override the RenderChildren method
- Within this method, it would render the children in the container, override it, do not call the base class version of it, and get the instances to the controls and render them.  This is where the complication arises because you have to.

Comment: Will I have a way to re-position the user controls in `RenderChildren`? How is this different from dynamically loading them using `LoadControl`?

Comment: Dynamically loading is fine too; you can go that route.  Dynamically loading controls can be a pain though, because you have to make sure they are added to the tree every time and in the same order I believe.  Yes, you render controls in the order you want, so you'd have full control over that too.

Comment: I wouldn't want to go the dynamic loading route. It hasn't been a pleasant experience in the past. Can you point me to a resource on how to override `RenderChildren` to specify the order? Thanks

Comment: I can't find it; however, take a look at this: http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/ASP.NET/ASPNET-Custom-Server-Controls-Breaking-the-Secrets-of-Rendering/  And realize your goal is to change the order of the rendering of children; in the example provided, in Render, there is a foreach; instead of using foreach, sort the controls first based on whatever criteria you have.

Comment: The link that you pointed to is about overriding `RenderChildren` in a custom Control. In my situation, I need to override methods in the page that hosts my user controls.

Comment: Not if you created a custom container control, as I mentioned earlier.  You would be overriding RenderChildren in a custom control that inherits from ContainerControl...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend rearranging on the client-side because

1. You will save a post-back.
2. You will make the website seamless.

How can do you that

1. Use a main div containing all controls and another containing a loading image. Toggle there visibility while rearranging the controls using javascript, or
2. You can set visibility:hidden to your body and then after rearranging set visibility:visible

The drawback of this approach is that you will have to use absolute positioning.

Comment: Doing it on the client side by setting the visibility gives the users a perception that loading the page is taking longer since they have to wait while the reordering is happening on the client before we make them visible.

Comment: Show a loading image when the controls are rearranging.

Comment: You also have to be careful here because then on every postback, you would have to rearrange them too.

Comment: @AshwinSingh I guess I could do that. I feel that the page will appear to be sluggish since reordering adds some time.